# react, Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: json, reactjs

code (Code that work) :

```
const member = [
  {
    "key": 14,
    "pid": "test3",
    "name": "test3",
    "gender": "other",
    "age": 3
  },
  {
    "key": 13,
    "pid": "test4",
    "name": "test4",
    "gender": "male",
    "age": 4
  },
  {
    "key": 12,
    "pid": "test5",
    "name": "test5",
    "gender": "male",
    "age": 5
  }
]



const print = member.filter(x => x.gender === 'male');
console.log(print);
```

code2 (Code i want to make it work) :

```
const originData = this.props.results;
const member = JSON.stringify(originData)



const print = member.filter(x => x.gender === 'male');
console.log(print);
```

error code(Errors that occur when using code2) :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
Container.render
D:/test/containers/member/Container.js:426
  423 | 
  424 |    
  425 | 
> 426 |    const space = member.filter(x => x.gender === 'male');
      | ^  427 |    console.log(space);
```

console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.results)) :

```
    [
    {"key":14,"pid":"test3","name":"test3","gender":"other","age":3},
    {"key":13,"pid":"test4","name":"test4","gender":"male","age":4},
    {"key":12,"pid":"test5","name":"test5","gender":"male","age":5}
    ]
```

console.log(this.props.results) :

[image]

Both const member data and json data are the same components, but I want to know why the top code works and the bottom code doesn't.

I want to classify using json data, not const member data, but it doesn't work. Let me know if you know

Comment: In code 2 member is string, cannot use string for filter

Comment: To complete the previous answer JSON.stringify will convert your object to a string.

Comment: Will it be solved by making it an array rather than a string?

Comment: We don't know what are your props but maybe you can simply do:
const member = this.props.results;

Comment: Thank you, but the result is the same. ;)

Comment: Can you share your props in the question ?

Comment: Added more content. Is this right what you need?

Comment: It should work without any transformation on your props: const member = this.props.results;

Comment: I thought so too. But the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

In the first example `member` is an array. In the second example `member` is a string. `filter` is not a method on a string.

To stop displaying `[Object object]` you can do `console.log(JSON.stringify(member))`

Comment: Do you know how to make the second code into an array rather than a string? Can you simply tell me?

Comment: change this const member = JSON.stringify(originData) to be const member = originData

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunately, the result is the same. ;)

Comment: It cannot be the same. This way works. .filter will not be undefined.

Comment: We added more content. I'll upload the entire code if necessary.

Comment: Try this JSON.parse(member).filter(x => x.gender === 'male');

Comment: It doesn't work, but thank you for your sincere reply.